# Firebase snapshot getValue could not pars int suddenly

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I hade a strange happening today with my Firebase project.

Suddenly the

```
AddressChatMessage chatMessage = snapshot.getValue(AddressChatMessage.class);
```

parsed everything ok for the `AddressChatMessage` except for one int.
Took me 2 hour until i tried this, setting the field to public

```
public int type;
```

Note I use this code for weeks without problem and today Android studio made some core updated to 2.3.2 and maybe that trigger this strange event.

Here´s the `AddressChatMessage.java` nothing strange except that the `public int type` cannot be private, if it is, it will be zero, that too is strange, usually Firebase give out a logcat warning when pojo parsing fails. I have 10 other modell classes like this with plenty of `int´s`

```
    @IgnoreExtraProperties
public class AddressChatMessage {

    // [START Firebase keys inside AddressChatMessage ]

    @Exclude
    public static final String TYPE = "type";

    @Exclude
    public static final String SENDER_ID = "senderId";

    @Exclude
    public static final String MESSAGE = "message";

    @Exclude
    public static final String FILENAME = "fileName";

    @Exclude
    public static final String DOWNLOAD_URI = "downloadUri";

    @Exclude
    public static final String TIME = "time";

    // [STOP Firebase keys inside AddressChatMessage ]

    public int type;

    private String senderId;

    private String message;

    private String fileName;

    private String downloadUri;

    @Exclude
    private long time;

    @Exclude
    private String messageId;

    public AddressChatMessage() {
    }

    public AddressChatMessage(int type, String senderUid) {
        this.senderId = senderUid;
        this.type = type;

    }

    public AddressChatMessage(int type, String senderUid, String message) {
        this.type = type;
        this.senderId = senderUid;
        this.message = message;
    }

    private int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getSenderId() {
        return senderId;
    }

    public void setSenderId(String senderId) {
        this.senderId = senderId;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getDownloadUri() {
        return downloadUri;
    }

    public void setDownloadUri(String downloadUri) {
        this.downloadUri = downloadUri;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public String getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }

    public void setMessageId(String messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put(TYPE, type);
        result.put(SENDER_ID, senderId);
        result.put(MESSAGE, message);
        result.put(FILENAME, fileName);
        result.put(DOWNLOAD_URI, downloadUri);
        result.put(TIME, time);
        return result;
    }
    @Exclude
    public boolean isTypeNormal() {
        return getType() == ChatAdapter.MessageType.NORMAL.ordinal();
    }

    @Exclude
    public boolean isTypeImage() {
        return getType() == ChatAdapter.MessageType.IMAGE.ordinal();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When cleaning the code using Lint. Lint suggested changes like "This can be private instead of public" - I accidentally set the `getType()` to private access.